# Why am I getting an OCI_ExecuteStm():The execution failed error when executing SQL statements?

Tags: c, oracle, ocilib

My code is as follows：

```
#include "ocilib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     OCI_Connection *cn = NULL; 
     OCI_Statement  *st = NULL;  
     OCI_Resultset  *rs = NULL;   
     char addr = NULL;
    if ( !OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT) )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("ORACLE","user", "passwd", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);  
    if ( cn != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n", OCI_GetVersionServer(cn));

       // OCI_ConnectionFree(cn);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connection failed!");
    }
    st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn);
    if (st == NULL)
    {
        printf("st is NULL,OCI_StatementCreate failed! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OCI_StatementCreate Success! \n");
    }
    char *sql =  "select FRIST_NO,USER_NAME, NUM_NO from \"table_name\" where NUM_NO like 20350;";  
    printf("%s\n", sql);
    if (OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, sql))  
    {
        printf("execute success!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("execute failed!\n");
    }
    
     rs = OCI_GetResultset(st); 

    while (OCI_FetchNext(rs)) 
    {
        OCI_Statement *st_gc = OCI_GetStatement(rs, 1);  
        OCI_Resultset *rs_gc = OCI_GetResultset(st_gc);

        while (OCI_FetchNext(rs_gc))
        {
            printf("GC_NO: %s\n",  OCI_GetString(rs_gc, 1)); 
        }
    }

    OCI_StatementFree(st);
    OCI_ConnectionFree(cn);
    OCI_Cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

The program execution results are as follows：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45XKB.png)
May I ask what is the reason for this and how should I solve it？

I have no problem executing SQL statements in NIVACAT, but sometimes I get an error ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.After  refreshing, the execution will be successful

Comment: If you had an error handler ([see the 'fetch example' in the documentation](https://vrogier.github.io/ocilib/doc/html/group___ocilib_c_api_fetching.html)) then you would see the actual Oracle error code. Is your table really called `table_name`, as a lower-case quoted identifier? Or is that supposed to be a placeholder for your real table name?

Comment: you need to be sure of the table name you're using, and remove the ';' at the end of the SELECT....

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)